# Binary file download

Tags: python, web-services, bottle

I'm building a server using python and bottle.

How can I handle a request for a binary file?

I have read that I should use flask. There is a way for doing that without using flask?

Comment: Bottle and Flask are not servers they are web frameworks.  Bottle and Flask both have some built in servers with them.  What to do mean, send binary file?  Do you want to send images and other files using Bottle and Bottles default server?  Look up Static Files in Bottles Documents.   Either way you do not need Flask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you should use `static_file` function:

```
from bottle import static_file    

@route('/download/<filename:path>')
def download(filename):
    return static_file(filename, root='/path/to/static/files', download=filename)
```

Comment: so, in bottle, if we want to download something, we must save it at first????? i mean in Flask(werkzeug) we can just save the file it in to `response.stream` .