# Using bottle to download a file?

Tags: python, file, bottle

In index.html I got the following button:

```
<button id="btn_file" type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="getFile()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></button>
```

In my javascript, picoreflow.js, I have this function:

```
function getFile()
{
    var cmd = {"cmd":"DL"};
    ws_control.send(JSON.stringify(cmd));
}
```

And in my picoreflowd.py, this is located in handle_control():

```
elif msgdict.get("cmd") == "DL":
                log.info("Download command received")
                static_file("downloadMe.txt", root='/home/pi/V2.3_Test/', download = "downloadMe.txt")
```

This is my github directory, which has the complete code: https://github.com/Ritzerk/V2.3_Test

I'm trying to work on open-source software, but I don't know anything about web-server. I tried to use static_file like suggested here: [Binary file download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725417/binary-file-download)

But its hard to know what I am doing wrong, since I have no website experience...

What's wrong with the way I am trying to download downloadMe.txt? The button doesn't even display on the website when I load it.

The file is located in the given directory. The V2.3_Test is located in /home/pi/.

Comment: How about focusing on one thing? Do the backend first. If it works you can work on the frontend.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank Sorry its literally my first time working with this sort of large application... how do I check just backend..?

Comment: The backend would just be Bottle and Python. Then try to download the file in your browser by just entering the URL.